# Replacing a string with an equal amount of underscores

Tags: c#

I'm trying to replace all characters of a string with underscores. From my readings a string is ordinarily immutable which means it cannot be modified superficially once it has been created.

I've decided to use StringBuilder to carry out the modification, though I need the underscores to be for display purposes only (hangman game) and not actually alter the value.

I've read through the Microsoft docs and feel like I'm doing the right thing but cannot understand why it won't work. Code below.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace randomtesting

{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str = "hello";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.Replace(str, "_", 0, str.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(str);

        }

    }
}
```

Edit -

What I ended up doing to get it to do what I wanted - unsure if ideal. Please provide feedback if there's a better way to do it, feel like it's not the most efficient way, but it works.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace randomtesting

{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str = "hello";
            string strDisplayedAsUnderscores = new string('_', str.Length);


            Console.WriteLine(strDisplayedAsUnderscores);
            char guess = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToLower()); //reads the user's guess
            int guessIndex = str.IndexOf(guess); //gets the index of the character guessed in relation to the original word
            StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(strDisplayedAsUnderscores); //converts the underscores into a StringBuilder string

            if (str.Contains(guess))  
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word.Replace('_', guess, guessIndex, 1));

                //if guess is contained in the original word
                //replace the indexed underscore with the 
                //guessed character

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update your **question** with "What I ended up doing to get it to do what I wanted......."  Because that part should be an answer.  Currently the question no loonger has any value because the answer is in the question...

Answer (score 2):

You want this [`System.String` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-string-ctor(system-char-system-int32))

```
string result = new string('_', str.Length);
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct. `out` is a reserved keyword, so change it to `@out`, or `output`.

Comment: Also, the side by side use of both `string` and `String` is making my eye twitch - I'd probably go with the `string` version :)

Comment: I was originally doing this, though I wanted to use the StringBuilder's replace() method to show a character in place of an underscore if guessed correctly, which I can't do if the word is not a StringBuilder string. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve with StringBuilder?

Comment: Unsure if ideal, but I think I worked it out. I used new string to convert the string into sequential underscores, then converted that into a StringBuilder object. I was then able to use the StringBuilder.Replace() method to put the guess in place of an underscore.